# Orchard: consume Webservice in Module

Tags: soap, web-config, orchardcms

I need to consume an existing SOAP-Webservice in a Module, which I am writing.

my web.config of my module contains:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebShopServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://10.0.0.123/LCWebservices/LC.MiscService/webshopservice.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebShopServiceSoap"
    contract="LCWebshopServiceReference.WebShopServiceSoap" name="WebShopServiceSoap" />
</client>
```

but my Module throws

```
Oops. Something went wrong ... sorry
An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. 
Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back

Es wurde kein standardmäßiges Endpunktelement gefunden, das auf den Vertrag
 "LCWebshopServiceReference.WebShopServiceSoap" im ServiceModel-
Clientkonfigurationsabschnitt verweist. 
Dies kann folgende Ursachen haben: Für die Anwendung wurde keine 
Konfigurationsdatei gefunden, oder im Clientelement wurde kein 
Endpunktelement gefunden, das diesem Vertrag entsprach.
```

which roughly translates, that the endpoint element could not be found.
I suspect this is due to the fact, that this web.config does not reside in the Orchard-Root.

What is the best to do about this??

thx
Reinhard

Answer (score 0):

You could use the web.config using

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
                new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + @"/Modules/MyModule/Web.config" }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        var factory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<IMyService>("IMyService", configuration, null);
        var client = factory.CreateChannel();
        client.MyMethod();
```

But i would not recommend this, basicly you have to extend the siteSettings content part with your own settings and store the address and binding information there. And then use those settings in your own IoC service class.

The service class can create a binding and a ChannelFactory to call the webservice.

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<WorkflowServiceRef.IWorkflowService>(
             binding,
             new EndpointAddress(endpointUri));
factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
factory.ConfigureChannelFactory();
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

channel.MyMethod()
```